# Transition colors in canvas on mouse enter/leave

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Using Canvas, how do I transition between colors in canvas?
For example in css you could have a transition like so

```
.btn { background-color: blue; transition: background-color 300ms ease-in-out; }
.btn:hover { background-color: red;  }
```

Css does a lot for you under the hood. Curious how we could have the same effect in canvas

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.btn');
const cx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawBtn(color) {
  const fillStyle = cx.fillStyle;
  cx.fillStyle = color;
  cx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}

const gradient = cx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "red");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "blue");
drawBtn(gradient);

canvas.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() { 
  drawBtn("blue");
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  drawBtn(gradient);
});
```

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 4px solid darkcyan;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="btn" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```